# Ionic run on android stopped working

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am building an ionic app. I had been able to deploy my app to my device easily enough, and then for whatever reason, it just won't deploy anymore. No error messages, I didn't update any software or anything; it just no longer deploys. I've tried about 10 different things and nothing has worked. I have no idea what to try anymore or even where to look for an error message. It's probably something dumb.

I'm thinking it might be something to do with the fact that I deployed my app earlier in the day, and then tried to make an update to it and redeploy- maybe it saw that I had already installed an app with the same name and refused? But then I tried deploying a completely different app and that failed too. I have no idea what to do next. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly add more details regarding your question.

```
D:\2bvision\cardapp>ionic info
```

cli packages: (C:\Users\Faran\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.10.0
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\Faran\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Comment: cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.2.0

System:

    Node : v10.2.1
    npm  : 5.6.0 
    OS   : Linux 4.2

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro

Comment: I knew it was something stupid... ANDROID_HOME somehow got unset :/

Comment: Good to know you have figure out on your own.